# SSRS 2016 IIF statement for font color not working in header

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, sql-server-2016, ssrs-2016

I have a couple reports that allow the user to change font colors with a parameter selection, this is the expression in the font color attribute:

```
=IIF(Parameters!Display.Value = true, "#000000", "#ffffff")
```

We just moved reports to a new 2016 instance and this expression is no longer working in the header.  It works fine for all the fields in the table / body of the report.

UPDATE:  I have tried using the colors names (black/white) but no difference.  The colors are correct when exported or printed, it is just the initial display of the report after clicking "run" that is showing the wrong colors.

UPDATE 2:  I have found an error - CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error. in File: powerbiglyphs-regular.eot

UPDATE 3: I opened the report in chrome and used the dev tools to poke around inside.  I found this in a css file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "PowerBIGlyphs-regular";
    src: url("../fonts/powerbiglyphs-regular.eot");
    src: url("../fonts/powerbiglyphs-regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
         url("../fonts/powerbiglyphs-regular.woff") format("woff"),
         url("../fonts/powerbiglyphs-regular.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("../fonts/powerbiglyphs-regular.svg#PowerBIGlyphs-regular") format("svg");
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
}
```

But the only file in the FONT folder is fonts/powerbiglyphs-regular.woff.  Is it possible I am getting the error due to missing font files?

Is there some quirk to 2016 that we need to know?

Comment: Did you try using the color names and see if that works?

Comment: I wasn't able to repro the issue. It worked as expected for me with both font color, and background color; both in the header. SSRS 2016.

Comment: Which browser are you using when you encounter the `@font-face` error?

Comment: IE. I've tried edge and 11.

Answer (score 1):

We run in the same issue and found a workaround by putting a space before the text place holder OR set the vertical alignment to top (or default).

Comment: Can you elaborate on "put a space before the text holder" ? And the vertical alignment of the header? or the text in the header?

Comment: I assume use a place holder to populate text of the column header? if not, do that first. Then you can add a space just before that place holder (not inside the holder's value expression but out side of the place holder). For "alignment" work around, the vertical alignment of header should work. Hope that helps.

Comment: Duc Tran, please add explanatory text in your answer, rather than as a comment, since comments can be unnoticed, thank you!